# "No version information available" - After installing Postgres

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed Postgres 9.1.4 on an `Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 64-bit` from here `http://www.openscg.com/se/postgresql/packages.jsp`, but right after installing many commands (programs) are throwing these following warnings in different combinations:

```
/opt/postgres/9.1/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available
/opt/postgres/9.1/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available
/opt/postgres/9.1/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available
```

Though this is not restricting anything, this is often getting very annoying. Is there a way to get rid of this without uninstalling Postgres?

Comment: Why not just install it from `apt-get install`?

Comment: Due to a network policy of the organization the postgres package size is over the allowable download limit. The network people downloaded and supplied this deb package from another computer where the limit is  a little loosened.

Comment: @intellidiot Totally irrelevant to your question, but the misguided security policy you're describing is a little misguided (Actually "Brain-damaged idea of a brain-damaged baboon" springs to mind). Restricting package download sizes doesn't improve security (there are exploits under 1M), and just creates stupid headaches like this one.

Comment: @intellidiot If that's intended as a "security" measure it's an even dumber policy than companies that require you to qualify every point-release and security update, so people land up still running PostgreSQL 8.1.0 in production. Since that's "truly incredibly stupid", this download-limit policy is award-winningly dim. Tell Bruce Scheier (http://www.schneier.com/) about them for a Stupid Security article. If it *isn't* supposedly for security (say, your WAN is expensive) then that's merely poor network management.

Comment: You both are right. I am just a victim here, don't have much say.

Answer (score 4):

This was actually discussed over on Unix & Linux ([Why does LD keep outputting “no version information available”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6186/9363)) -- Short answer: The libraries that Postgres is looking for were compiled with different tools (which didn't include the symbol versioning information).

The only "solution" is to rebuild your local libraries with symbol versioning (or rebuild Postgres on the local machine / use a package *for your OS*) so it doesn't care.

---

As a general rule you should not be installing random `.deb` packages on Ubuntu systems -- or any other OS for that matter.
If your OS vendor (or software vendor) supplies a package for what you need, use that one. If they don't you should roll your own package, or build from source to avoid problems like this one.  In this case it's just a mild inconvenience, but there are other (substantially worse) possible outcomes too...